# Open selected files with open_mfdataset

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a folder containing a lot of files with similar names and I want to open two of them with `xarray` so I get one array (with the time axis consistent).

I know that I can open multiple files with the *

Example:

`xarray.open_mfdataset('folder/*.nc')` would open all netcdf files in the folder.

Now, say I have `file_01`, `file_02` and `file_03` in folder.

How can I open `file_01` & `file_02`, but not `file_03` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xr.open_mfdataset()` can accept wildcards, as you said, but it can also accept an explicit list of files if you want to specify them.

So in your case, you could use:

`xr.open_mfdataset(['folder/file1.nc','folder/file2.nc'])`